# Binary operations and Simple Solver

Tags: c++, qt, cad, openscenegraph, finite-element-analysis

I'm making a small demo to suggest Qt and OSG at my company to make some things easier to everyone working with me. But I need to do it rather quickly. I need a library for 2D and 3D binary operations on 2D and 3D geometry that will give a result mesh that can draw in OSG at the output. I also need a simple solver and mesher with which I could just define temperature on a tetrahedras within a mesh or nodes within a geometry and view a solution with OSG. I don't make solvers, I work with UI and some inner routines thus I need these libraries or something I can make a demo of a simple CAE software based on Qt and OSG. Can you suggest something?

Comment: VTK (www.vtk.org) can probably do what you want, but good luck doing what you are asking 'quickly'.

Comment: @cmannett85 Thank you very much, though the whole idea will be not so 'quick', it will be better just to make a presentation of what each package can do with slides of some package samples.